# Using string variable from regex in xpath contains function

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath

Im new to Selenium and Python .I have the following regex that I use to match +ve 4 digits in a webpage.How do i use an regex expression in xpath contains after converting it to string using str function

Suppose I have an xpath
          `[@id="7719"]/td[2]/span`

And use the regex

`number=re.findall(r'^\d{4}$',b)`

to match any +ve 4 digit

The xpath in selenium terms can be expressed as

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[contains(@id,'7718')]/td[2]/span""")`

How do i use number in place of 7718?

There are no other elements like id or css selector we can use.So i opted xpath and regex. Also since my Xpath  is version 1 it doesnt accept matches function which i tried already

I tried doing 
`driver.find_element_by_xpath("""// [contains(@id,'+ str(number)+')]/td[2]/span""") and 
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""// [contains(@id,'"+ str(number)+'")]/td[2]/span""")'`

The expected output would be to use any positive 4 digit number using regex.

Comment: Instead of using `regex` update the question with the relevant HTML

Comment: What is `+ve` supposed to mean? Write "consecutive" when you mean "consecutive". Avoid chat speak, this website is not a chat.

Comment: @Tomalak.     +ve means positive.Apologies for that.Im used to short hand writing too much

Comment: @DebanjanB I posted the required stuff in here.Why is HTML needed? My doubt lies in how to use a string from regex in xpath

Comment: Well then fix this in your post. It's really not helpful to have these kinds of unclear abbreviations in a technical description.

Answer (score 0):

`find_element_by_xpath` method accepts `String` so

```
Str1="// [contains(@id,"
Str2= "'{}'".format(str(1779))
Str3=")]/td[2]/span"
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//[contains(@id,"+ "'{}'".format(str(1779))+")]/td[2]/span")
```

Check below execution statement is generating as expected
[image]

Comment: Nice.Thanks for that. Can i also use the regex string in the place of str 7719 number?

Comment: I tried this and the syntax seems to be an issue here. Plus Python 3 use format?

Comment: can you share exactly what you have used ?

Comment: the same thing you posted above

Comment: `number=re.findall(r'^\d{4}$',b)`

if `b` here is a string e.g. "some4you" then you can use like 

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//[contains(@id,"+ "'{}'".format(number)+")]/td[2]/span")`

Comment: JainOkay.Thankyou